# Android AlertBox then ProgressDialog. ProgessDialog not showing

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-progressbar

Seems there is several variations on this theme. I display an `AlertBox` to the user do want to save this item out? If they respond OK then I want the `Alertbox` to go away to be replaced by `ProgressDialog` box then when item is done being saved out it dismisses.

The current code below shows the Ok/Cancel `AlertBox` and dismiss properly and shows toast correctly. But if the user selects OK the `ProgressDialog` shows after all is completed and never goes away. The OK/Cancel button stays depressed until item is saved. If the user presses OK I want the `AlertBox` to go away and then display the `ProgressDialog` and dismiss it when done saving.

```
{
 Vibrate(ClickVibrate); 
 final ProgressDialog Dialog = ProgressDialog.show(v.getRootView().getContext(), "Loading", "Please wait...", true);
if(AlertDialogProcessing==0)
{    
ProgressDialog progress;  
final String title="Save Item";
final String message="Press OK to save or CANCEL.";
final String ok="OK";
final String cancel="CANCEL";

final AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertbox.setCancelable(true);
alertbox.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
alertbox.setTitle(title);
alertbox.setMessage(message);
alertbox.setNegativeButton(cancel, null);

final AlertDialog dlg = alertbox.create();

 alertbox.setPositiveButton(ok,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
   {  
     public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
     {  
      dlg.dismiss();
      Dialog.show();
      Vibrate(ClickVibrate); 
      Drawable drawable= getItem(imageSelect);   
      AlertDialogProcessing=1;   
      //task that takes 3 seconds
      AlertDialogProcessing=0;
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item Saved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
    } 
  });
 alertbox.setNegativeButton(cancel,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){ public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1){AlertDialogProcessing=0; Vibrate(ClickVibrate); } });
 alertbox.show();
 }
 Dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling both `ProgressDialog.show()` and `ProgressDialog.dismiss()` inside the positive button's `onClick()`, no wonder the `ProgressDialog` doesn't show. If the saving process takes some time such that you need a `ProgressDialog`, I'd strongly recommend using the `AsyncTask` class. It runs a task on a worker thread and gives you a possibility to update the UI with the current task progress. Hope this helps.

Comment: I havent mastered asynch yet. The time waiting to do something else is ok. How should I structure the code. I've modified the code displayed to show what I have.

Comment: @user1445716, Describe your app's saving process please

Comment: I decided to go ahead and figure out Asynch to do this as you suggested. Cool. I posted question and my eventual answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494002)