# Android ProgressDialog and AlertDialog with AsyncTask incompatibility?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, android-alertdialog

I've isolated an issue I am having when showing a ProgressDialog while an AsyncTask is executing and then trying to show an AlertDialog when onPostExecute is executed.
The steps to reproduce are:

1-Run the task

2-Before the task has finished press Home button

3-When you assume the task is finished return to the app

4-AlertDialog is not shown and a low bright (like disabled) screen is shown.

I've discovered that moving the dialog.dismiss() line to the end of the onPostExecute method fixes the problem... But this is weird, isn't it?

Source code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onClickButton(View view) {
    new MyAsyncTask(this).execute();
}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    Context ctx;

    public MyAsyncTask(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void value) {
        dialog.dismiss();

        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
        alertbox.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
        alertbox.setMessage("Message");
        alertbox.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        alertbox.show();

        // dialog.dismiss(); If I remove it from above and put this line here, it will work ok
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @Asok I don't see why dialog.dismiss() would mean that the AsyncTask is complete, it is a method to close the progress dialog.

Comment: Refer this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494002/android-async-task-to-show-an-alertdialog