# Dialog Box Close Automatically

Tags: android, dialog

I would like to add dialog box in my coding. The dialog box is able to pop out. Suppose the dialog will close after user press the ok button, but the dialog box close automatically. This is my code. Any problem?

```
private void updataAccount(int type){
    Iterator<AccountData> iteratorSort = commondata.account.values().iterator();
    while (iteratorSort.hasNext()){
        AccountData data = iteratorSort.next();
        if(data.id == Integer.parseInt(accountId[account_spn.getSelectedItemPosition()]))
        {
            if(type == INCOME_MODE){
                data.balance = data.balance+Double.parseDouble(value);
                commondata.updateAccount(data);
            }else if(type == PAYOUT_MODE){
                data.balance = data.balance-Double.parseDouble(value);
                commondata.updateAccount(data);
                if(data.balance < 0)
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder
                    .setTitle("Care Money")
                    .setMessage("Your amount in this account is negative!")
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                        {       
                               dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    });                     
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();
                }
            }
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you say automatically, does it do it after a certain amount of time or event?

Comment: @frogmanx yes.it close automatically after 1 second the dialog box pop out.

Comment: I don't see anything that causes this??

Comment: I don't think it closes automatically.. I tried code too.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.show();
```

Instead of this

```
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6494201/2594077  , check this if you want to implement dialog in AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

Chitan Please try this code It is working fine for me hope it will help u somehow

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                     builder.setTitle("Error");
                     builder.setMessage(error)
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    error="";
                                }
                            });
                     AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                     alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `AsyncTask` that displays the dialog, then sleeps for 1000 milliseconds, then closes the dialog.

Comment: how? sorry i am a newbie.

Comment: Perfect and complete reference, cheers: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html